# Impossible to require a module in VueJS using require.context although the path is right

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs3, require

I'm trying to require every `description.js` file in a subfolder. I wrote these lines:

```
require.context(
      './',
      true,
      /description.js$/,
    ).keys()
    .forEach((k) => {
      console.log(k);
      console.log(`${k.replace('./', '@/components/subfolder/').replace('.js', '')}`)
      console.log('@/components/subfolder/tool/description');
      const path = '@/components/subfolder/tool/description'; // TRY
      const t = require(path); // TRY
      //   const t = require(`${k.replace('./', '@/components/subfolder/').replace('.js', '')}`); // COMMENT 1
      //   const t = require('@/components/subfolder/tool/description'); // COMMENT 2
      console.log(t);
    });
```

requiring directly using "COMMENT 2" works like a charm, but what I would like is to loop through all the files I want to require, so the "COMMMENT 1" would be great. So, for some reason, it appears that you have to directly write the path in the `require`. I tried the two lines commented "TRY", and it doesn't work, surprisingly!

Here is the error I get in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module '@/components/subfolder/tool/description'
```

Can somebody explain how I can dynamically loop through the subfolder?

Comment: Why aren't you running this like in the first example [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#context-module-api)? `function importAll(r) {  r.keys().forEach(r); }   importAll(require.context(...));`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how it could help me.

Comment: The code is a little obscure. The `require.context` call returns a function, which if you call it with the values returned from `.keys()`, actually requires them in to your module. `.forEach(r)` is the same as `.forEach(key => r(key))`. Try it.

Comment: If you want to do it your way, you need to supply a literal first in the require method: `require('@/components/subfolder/' + k.replace('./',  '').replace('.js', ''));`

Comment: That is what I'm saying: it doesn't work if I don't put just a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, or at least a working answer:

```
function importAll(r) {
  r.keys().forEach((key) => {
    outils.value[key] = r(key).details;
  });
}

importAll(require.context(
  './',
  true,
  /description.js$/,
));
```